# proof that length of difference of projections implies equality of length of normals

Tags: convex-optimization

Hi: I'm reading a book on optimization and there is an interesting stated theorem but I don't know how to prove it.

Notation: Let $P_{c}(x)$ denote the projection of onto a convex set  c
which is a subspace of $R^{n}$.

Then, the theorem is the following:

If y and x are 2 points in $R^{n}$, then,

if $|| P_{c}(y) - P_{c}(x) ||= || y - x ||$, then

$x - P_{c}(x) = y - P_{c}(y)$

Thanks to anyone who could provide a reference or a proof. This is not homework.  I'm just studying this material for fun.

Comment: Decompose $x$ and $y$ as $x=P_c x + (P_c^\perp) x$. Then, use triangle inequality and its conditions for equality.

Comment: Did you accidentally reverse the sign on one side of that last equation?

Comment: "Projection on a convex set" meaning the closest point in the (presumably closed) convex set.

Comment: Since $c$ is a subspace, $P_c(y)-P_c(x)=P_c(y-x)$. Seems like that is important :-)

Comment: @David.K: thanks. I had a typo in the final line. My apologies.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks. I should have said projection onto a closed convex set. Apologies for that also.

Comment: Also, if anyone knows of a book or notes where topics like the one in this proof are explained in detail for "dummies", ( i.e: not rockefellar or lemarchal )  and where there might be figures to aid in the understanding, it's appreciated.

Comment: @Batman: Thank you for the hint. I will try that approach. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $C$ is a subspace, we have
$$
\langle x-P_C(x),P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle=0;
$$
$$ 
\langle y-P_C(y),P_C(y)-P_C(x)\rangle=0.
$$
Adding two equalities we obtain
$$
\langle x-P_C(x)-(y-P_C(y)),P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle=0
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\langle x-y, P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle=\|P_C(x)-P_C(y)\|^2.
$$
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|(x-P_C(x))-(y-P_C(y))\|^2&=&\|(x-y)-(P_C(x)-P_C(y))\|^2\\
&=&\|x-y\|^2-2\langle x-y, P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle+\|P_C(x)-P_C(y)\|^2\\
&=&\|P_C(x)-P_C(y)\|^2-2\|P_C(x)-P_C(y)\|^2+\|P_C(x)-P_C(y)\|^2\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $x-P_C(x)=y-P_C(y)$.

**Remark.** We explain why we have
$$
\langle x-P_C(x),P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle=0,
$$
where $C$ is a subspace.

Indeed, by the characterization of the metric projection
$$
\langle x-P_C(x), u-P_C(x)\rangle\leq 0 \quad \forall u\in C.
$$
Substituting $u=P_C(y)\in C$ into the equality we obtain
$$
\langle x-P_C(x), P_C(y)-P_C(x)\rangle\leq 0.
$$
Substituting $u=2P_C(x)-P_C(y)\in C$ into the equality we obtain
$$
\langle x-P_C(x), P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle\leq 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
\langle x-P_C(x),P_C(x)-P_C(y)\rangle=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I will print out and go over carefully and then check the answer. It's appreciated.

Comment: Wait, $C$ isn't a halfspace, it's a subspace.

Comment: @Michael Grant: Thank you. The assertion is also true for subspace.

Comment: @mark leeds: Please accept my solution if you find interesting.

Comment: @Blind: Thank you but I need to understand it first and then I will definitely accept it. But I don't follow all the steps yet. I'll get back to you if I can't figure them ( the ones I don't follow yet ) out myself.

Comment: @mark leeds: The above is the complete answer. If you have any question please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Blind: That was an amazing answer. I don't know what else to say besides thanks. It took me a while to understand the algebra and the various relations but you explained it all beautfully. I'm going to ask another question ( more of a confirmation ) using a different thread. Feel free to read that one also. Thanks again.

Comment: @mark leeds: I am waiting for your question. If I can I will try my best to help you.